Remote Video Player - For Halloween Show
Looking to setup a Pi to play video though a 1080p projector for a Halloween show. I need a player that I can use python code to select a local video file, play if full screen, and stop it (screen to black).  Then I can setup an simple web server to receive commands from the show controller.  Any suggestions on a video player for the task?  Thanks

not Raspberry Pi specific ... it's a general linux question ... but, a better fit at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

I don't want to encourage you to stay here as this is a general Linux question. So add a comment if you have moved this to a different stackexchange group. Going on, most Linux distros are setup as work stations or personal computers. Is sounds like you want a Kiosk (i.e. complete autonomous or remote control of the screen). There are plenty of Linux / Kiosk howtos.
